# Calculate $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Pr(X_n=i|X_0=6)$ for markov chain with given transition matrix

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Given is a Markov Chain $(X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ on $X =\{1,...,7\}$ with transition matrix

$$P=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3} \\
\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&0 \\
\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3} \\
0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0&0&\frac{1}{2}&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1 \\
\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3}&0&0&\frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}$$

---

$(X_n)$ is not irreducible because states $2,3,5,6$ are inaccessible by other states. I can calculate a Probability $Pr(X_n=i|X_0=6)$ for a fixed $n$, but I don't know the mathematical way to calculate the limit as $n$ approaches $\infty$.

I have calculated the (unique) stationary distribution $\pi=[\frac{1}{3},0,0,\frac{1}{3},0,0,\frac{1}{3}]$ and it is clear to me that $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}Pr(X_n=i|X_0=6)=\frac{1}{3}$ for $i \in \{1,4,7\}$ and $0$ otherwise. Could someone tell me how I can calculate this limit mathematically?

Comment: If you can compute the limit of $$\frac13P(X_n=i\mid X_0=1)+\frac13P(X_n=i\mid X_0=4)+\frac13P(X_n=i\mid X_0=7)$$ then you are done. Can you?

Comment: No, that is exactly my problem. When I write it down for some n I can see that it converges, But that is not the correct mathematical way, is it?

Comment: What do you find for $P(X_n=i\mid X_0=1)$, say?

Comment: for $i=1, n=1: \frac{1}{3}, n=2: 3*\frac{1}{9} = \frac{1}{3}, n=3: 9*\frac{1}{27} = \frac{1}{3}$ and so on, so $3^{n-1}*\frac{1}{3^n}$ for arbitrary n. This is the same for $i \in \{1,4,7\}$, for the other values it is $0$.

Comment: Likewise, conditionally on $X_0=7$, every $X_n$ is uniform on $\{1,4,7\}$. Thus, you are done since, conditionally on $X_0=6$, $X_1=7$ almost surely.